# Problems getting Credentials in Java for GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to access the Google Drive API from my Java servlet that is running on Google App Engine. I got it working locally but when deploying to Google App Engine I had to change some things, such as using a Datastore that doesn't work on the file system. I can't get this working and I based this flow on a Calendar related example from Google. My code looks like this:

```
private static  Credential authorize(HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT, DataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
            ConcreteSheetWriter.class.getResourceAsStream(SECRET_PATH);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
   /*

   The credentials before deploying to GAE. Problems when deploying on GAE
   Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    */
  final  String userId = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getUserId();
  final  Credential credential = flow.loadCredential(userId);
  return credential;
}
```

The current problem is that I get a null pointer exception on the line where I assign userId to a value. In the comment you can see how I created the Credential instance before GAE. I'm not even sure that the "flow.loadCredential(...)" is the right way to go. If anyone here has any advice on how to get this working then I would appreciate it a lot.